# Slider control with Move-To-Position behavior

Tags: slider, windows-phone

In this page about the Slider control on Windows Phone, in the last paragraph, a behavior is mentionned:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202877(v=vs.92).aspx

> You can also customize the behavior of a Slider control. Depending on
>   how it’s being used, a Slider control might benefit from the following
>   behaviors:
>
> - Move-to-Position: the thumb jumps to the position of the
>     contact.
> - Snap-to-Tick: the thumb jumps to the tick value that is closest to its
>     current position in the direction of the contact.

But I can't find in the class reference page where those behavior can be specified
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.95).aspx

I'm interested in the Move-To-Position one since the other one is the default behavior of the control.

Answer (score 0):

I can;t see that paragraph in the link you specify above.  Wrong link?  Normally to attach behaviors you would do something like this in XAML

```
<Slider>
   <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <Behaviours:MyCustomBehavior MyDependProp="someValue" />
   </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Slider>
```

Comment: Apologies, I see it now (the first link).  The article seems to be suggesting those would be good behaviors rather than state they are already available - at least thats how I read it.

Comment: Yes I know about Behaviors, I was thinking about a more specific answer.

Comment: Isn't it just a case of writing a Behavior to do it? The docs say it would be nice to have it, i.e. it doesn't currently exist. The implementation I think would be simple in a Behavior. Just wire into the Tap gesture and go from there.