# Move-to-Position behavior of slider control in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, slider, position

I wanted to know how can I make the slider thumb to jump to the position where I click on the slider. In other words, how can I retrieve the value where the user clicked on the slider (and then I could set the slider's value).

This question is just like:

[Slider control with Move-To-Position behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621997/slider-control-with-move-to-position-behavior)

But there is no available solution.

Because slider control in wp7 has not **IsMoveToPointEnabled** property, so customization is the only way to get the function IMO. I use the [following codes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/47a7d247-1e94-4699-a036-c10feba568d3/):

```
public class CustomSlider: Slider {
  public CustomSlider() {
    DefaultStyleKey = typeof (Slider);
  }
  public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    RepeatButton rb;
    rb = base.GetTemplateChild("HorizontalTrackLargeChangeIncreaseRepeatButton") as RepeatButton;
    rb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(rb_MouseMove);
    rb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(rb_Click);
    rb = base.GetTemplateChild("HorizontalTrackLargeChangeDecreaseRepeatButton") as RepeatButton;
    rb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(rb_MouseMove);
    rb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(rb_Click);
    rb = base.GetTemplateChild("VerticalTrackLargeChangeIncreaseRepeatButton") as RepeatButton;
    rb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(rb_Click);
    rb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(rb_MouseMove);
    rb = base.GetTemplateChild("VerticalTrackLargeChangeDecreaseRepeatButton") as RepeatButton;
    rb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(rb_Click);
    rb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(rb_MouseMove);
    //rb.
  }
  Point ps;
  void rb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    ps = e.GetPosition(this);
  }
  public event EventHandler MyClickEvent;
  void rb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (MyClickEvent != null) MyClickEvent(this, new PositionEventArgs(ps));
  }
}
public class PositionEventArgs: EventArgs {
  public Point Position {
    set;
    get;
  }
  public PositionEventArgs() {}
  public PositionEventArgs(Point p) {
    Position = p;
  }
}
```

I try my best, but until now, I just can't get it worked. The **MOUSEOVER** Event on **RepeatButton** embedded in slider never fire, even when **RepeatButton** is alone in the xaml. In fact, just **CLICK** Event is fired in my experiment.

I see most video player has this function, so I really want to know how to make it in my player.